# My sql Error Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * ,
  (SELECT ZoneName 
   FROM zone_message_master 
   WHERE ZoneID = zoneid) 'ZoneName' 
FROM zone_master 
WHERE ZoneID=zoneid;
```

This is a query running in stored procedure and I am getting Error

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

Can any one tell me what I have done wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you have more than one entry in  `zone_message_master` for your `zoneid`.
This query will be more correct:

```
SELECT zm.* , zmm.ZoneName 
FROM zone_master zm
JOIN zone_message_master zmm ON zm.ZoneID=zmm.ZoneID
WHERE zm.ZoneID=zoneid;
```

Answer (score 2):

> What I have done wrong here?

The error, you got, is pretty clear. The subquery must return exactly one row, you can limit the number of rows using `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1`.

> How can I fix that?

You didn't need a subquery for that, `JOIN` the two tables directly instead like so:

```
SELECT z.ZoneId, zm.ZoneName
FROM zone_message_master zm
INNER JOIN zone_master z ON zm.ZoneId = z.ZoneId
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably as clear as the error message you got. You can trick the subquery to return only one row, but this is not the case. You intention as I see is that the table `zone_message_master` should have unique `ZoneID` values. To be correct you should create a unique index on `zone_message_master.ZoneID` column. This will of course require some cleaning in that table, but finally will alow you to be sure it works correct.